# How to apply DRY to a series of HTML files that have an almost identical <div></div> block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a chain of pages that each contain this HTML

```
  <div class ="container">
    <h3>PROVIDER ENROLLMENT APPLICATION</h3>
  </div>

  <div class ="tabs">
     <a href="tabsA.html"><span>Sec A</span></a>
     <a href="tabsB.html"><span>Sec B</span></a>
     <a href="tabsC.html"><span>Sec C</span></a>
     <a href="tabsD.html"><span>Sec D</span></a>
     <a href="tabsE.html"><span>Sec E</span></a>
     <a href="tabsF.html"><span class="active">Sec F</span></a>
     <a href="tabsG.html"><span>Sec G</span></a>
     <a href="tabsH.html"><span>Sec H</span></a>
     <a href="tabsI.html"><span>Sec I</span></a>
     <a href="tabsJ.html"><span>Sec J</span></a>
     <a href="tabsK.html"><span>Sec K</span></a>
     <a href="tabsL.html"><span>Sec L</span></a>
     <a href="tabsM.html"><span>Sec M</span></a>
  </div
```

Excepting each page has only it's own href attribute displayed as "active", this being the page for tab F. Is there a way to have this block of code used only once activating the selected pages href attributes when selected?

Comment: Have a look at web components: https://css-tricks.com/modular-future-web-components/

Comment: uh, any scripting language... ever.

Comment: You could also explore different HTML templating engines. There is plenty of them out there. I personally use http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/

Answer (score 0):

**You can try something like this (running it after the html block or on `load`):**

```
function getLastLoc() {
    var path = location.href.split('/');
    path = path[path.length - 1] || path[path.length - 2];
    path = path.split('?')[0].split('#')[0];
    return path;
}
$('[href="' + getLastLoc() + '"] span').addClass('active');
```

Comment: To OP - using the attribute selector, like in this, is probably cleaner than my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need the active class to be applied client-side:

```
var currentPage = window.location.pathname.substring(1);
$('.tabs a').each(function(index, $tag){
  var link = $tag.attr('href');
  if(link === currentPage) {
    $('span', $tag).addClass('active');
  }
});
```